# JQuery $.ajax requests with json responses

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

A JSON returned as response to this request is not recognized.

```
request = $.ajax({
        url: "form_handler.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: serializedData
});
```

The php code in `form_handler.php` which returns the response:

```
if ($success) {
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
}
```

And thus in:

```
request.done(data) 
{
    alert(data.success);     // error: cannot read property of 'success' of null 
}
```

Comment: Try to set the error handler to see if there's a problem while performing the request. Also, are you sure there isn't any other error in the rest of the php script?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  If it's less than 5.4, [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-pretty-print) is not defined. Depending on your error settings, this may cause the script to fail silently. Try it without that option: `echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true"));`

Comment: @Paul Roub In this case (script fails) `jqXHR.done()` shouldn't be called

Comment: @PaulRoub may be right, but not because the script would fail. An undefined constant would be a notice and therefore it would assume null as value and it would behave like default. Instead, it may be that the notice was printed due to display_errors settings and therefore jquery can't automatically decode the json object giving null as data

Comment: @PaulRoub indeed you are correct, my PHP version is less than 5.4 and thus removing the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` makes the json valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this as a wrap up of the answers and comments posted.

As @jetawe and @FelixKling pointed out, it would be a best practice to specify the Content-Type of the response, so add this at the head of the php script:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

@hindmost pointed out that the script is not failing since `jqXHR.done()` is actually called.

My guess is that there is a failure decoding the json object when `$.ajax` automatically decodes it (because of `dataType: "json"`)

As @PaulRoub noticed, `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` exists from the PHP version 5.4 so, if you have an older version of PHP, that constant wouldn't exists, throwing an error of level `E_NOTICE` and assuming the value `null`. Passing `null` (equal to 0) as a value `json_encode` would work anyway (assuming default behavior)

My second guess is that you have `display_errors = 1` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` so PHP is printing out the error breaking the json.

I hope I guessed right!

Comment: In my scenario, yes, `null` would be successfully parsed from the JSON response. This would lead directly to the reported error - "cannot read property of 'success' of null"

Comment: @PaulRoub `null` would be the value of `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, so the script would go forward with `json_encode(array("success"=>"false"), null);` giving the actual converted json object, not a null. But if the notice is appended in the output, then the json object is corrupted, and jquery will fail decoding it, giving `data = null`. Be aware that the conversion is done before calling the callback method and `data` will contain the converted object

Answer (score 1):

That code looks ok, but maybe handling it all in the ajax call itself would help debug your issue.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "form_handler.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: serializedData,
    success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
         console.log(data.success);
         console.log($.parseJSON(data));
    }
});
```

Please add your response object if you get one so we can see the structure - and i'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send JSON header in , set it in your php file

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: It's very good practice but it should not be required if `dataType: 'json'` is set.

Answer (score 0):

This is Ajax request:

```
jquery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function(serverData) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(serverData);
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
```

Php response:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true'));
```